# Symfony 3 ChoiceType - Attribute empty_data ignored

Tags: php, forms, symfony, attributes

I have a problem with my search form. It is possible that my select contains nothing.
This is why I would like to display a default message when it is empty.

However when I set my 'empty_data' attribute, nothing happens, always my empty select.
My FormType :

```
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('organisation',ChoiceType::class,array(
            'choices' => $options['distributeurs'],
            'choice_label' => function ($value, $key, $index) {
                    return $value->getOrganisation();
                },
            'choice_value' => 'id',
            'empty_data' => 'No distributor found'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'distributeurs' => 'ProjectBundle\Entity\Organisation\Organisation',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'projectbundle_organisation_search';
    }
```

[image: emptySelect]

And at the level of the controller :

```
 $distributeurs = $em->getRepository('ProjectBundle:Organisation\Organisation')->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->where('a.id IN (:distributeurs)')->setParameter('distributeurs',$organisationDistriId)->getQuery()->execute();
        $form = $this->createForm('ProjectBundle\Form\Organisation\OrganisationDistributeurType', null, array(
            'distributeurs' => $distributeurs,
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('admin_organisations_index'),
            'method' => 'GET',
        ));
```

The form and information work correctly, there is just the 'empty_data' attribute that is not displayed.

The 'placeholder' attribute works but that's not what I want.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please post your code, not pictures of your code.

Comment: It is done, sorry

Comment: `empty_data` is the value which is passed back to Symfony when no option is selected on the front-end of the form. It's never displayed on the form itself. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#empty-data

Comment: Ahh okay ! Do you have an idea to display a message when there are no items?

Comment: Like putting a placeholder only if I do not have items in `$options['distributors']?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to post your code next time and not a picture because that is not clear.

In your Form Builder try to create the select in this way (Placeholder is implemented from version 2.6):

```
$builder->add('organisation', ChoiceType::class, array(
'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',
));
```

Comment: Yes yes, sorry ^^'.
So I'm going to go on the placeholder, it's not such a bad solution.